# CGAL normalize vector

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

I want to normalize the vectors, yet I could not understand how to do such a basic operation. There does not exist a direct method like Vector_3::normalize().

I call squared_length() and then CGAL::sqr_root() to find the vector length. Then when I want to divide my vector to its length, compiler does not permit since CGAL types are not compatible. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What kernel are you using? Some kernels do not support square roots... (there is no `CGAL::sqr_root`) Also, are you sure you need to normalize?

Answer (score 1):

I'm expanding here the comment by @MarcGlisse.

There are two scenarios - you want exact calculations or you don't. In the first case you can use the `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel_with_sqrt` and the normalized vector will be exact.

In the second case you can use many kernels, but the normalized vector will probably have the length, slightly different from `1`. Also some kernels don't have the function `CGAL::sqrt` at all - however you can always convert squared distances to the `double` type, using the function `CGAL::to_double`. Another way is to use a function `CGAL::approximate_sqrt`, which automatically does this conversion if it's necessary. These conversions make calculations not exact. Please see the example below:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel_with_sqrt.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>

using KernelExactWithSqrt = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel_with_sqrt;
using KernelExact = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel;
using KernelInexact = CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>;

template <typename T>
auto normalize(T const& V)
{
  auto const slen = V.squared_length();
  auto const d = CGAL::approximate_sqrt(slen);
  return V / d;
}

template <typename T>
auto check()
{
  typename T::Point_2 const p{0, 0}, q{1, 1};
  auto const n = normalize(typename T::Vector_2{p, q});
  return n.squared_length() == 1;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "====== Exact kernel with square root ======" << std::endl;
  std::cout << check<KernelExactWithSqrt>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "====== Inexact kernel ======" << std::endl;
  std::cout << check<KernelInexact>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "====== Exact kernel with automatic conversion to double ======" << std::endl;
  std::cout << check<KernelExact>() << std::endl;
}
```

The output:

```
====== Exact kernel with square root ======
1
====== Inexact kernel ======
0
====== Exact kernel with automatic conversion to double ======
0
```

So, this example shows that the `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel_with_sqrt` guarantees you that the normalized vector will be what you expect.

Comment: Note that you can use `CGAL::approximate_sqrt()`, which will either call `CGAL::sqrt()` if the number type supports exact square roots, or will use an intermediate (possibly inexact) conversion to `double` as shown above.

Comment: @Mael - thank you, I didn't know about the `CGAL::approximate_sqrt`, I've updated the answer